# how can I git-revise configs in my /etc/ dir? (sudo has different keys..)

Tags: ubuntu, git, configuration

I'd like to keep some of the folders in my /etc/ dir git-revised, cause I'm quite new to server administration and am constantly messing around in my /etc/nginx/ and /etc/bind/ directories.

I've heard of people git-revising their either /etc/ directories, but that seems a bit like overkill, as at this point I'm only messing in those 2 subdirectories.

The problem I'm having is that if I sudo my git operations, I don't have the right pubkeys to push to my remote repo (bitbucket).
But if I don't sudo, I need to mess around with all the permissions (again, not very pro at this).

Does anyone know best practices for managing their configs? or how I should solve this problem?

Thanks,
Dean.

PS. It's Ubuntu 12.04, Git, nginx, bind9, amazon aws, bitbucket...

Comment: I could symlink them into my dropbox instead...
Is that a dumb idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make it hierarchical.

Have an ordinary user use bitbucket as the remote and store the repo in their home directory. Then have `/etc/` use the repo in the homedir as the remote.

In other words...

- Git repo used by `root` in `/etc`/ has remote of `/home/dean-rather/git/etc/`.
- Git repo used by `dean-rather` in `/home/dean-rather/git/etc/` has remote of `git://git@bitbucket.com/dean-rather/etc.git`.

Comment: ok giving that a try..

Comment: having heaps of trouble with making a repo to begin with...
`cd /etc/nginx` `sudo git init` `sudo git add ./*` `sudo git init -a -m "initial commit"` `sudo git branch nginx` -> error: `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'` ... `sudo git branch` -> blank..

Comment: To create a branch use `git checkout -b <newbranch>`.